# how to show the linearization result in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I tried to use the linearization function in Dymola, but it seems when the result's dimension is large, Dymola won't show the result.
My question is:
How could I print the result or where to find it?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

What you can do, is assign the result to a variable. This can be done using the `Outputs` group as shown in the screenshot below. If you e.g. enter "sys" in the field for `ss`, you will get a record `sys`, in which you can access the matrices/vectors by typing `sys.A`, `sys.B` etc., which I've tested for a system of size 200x200. Typing this into the command line will display the content. Of course this record not only for outputting it, but also for post-processing.

[image]

The only thing this actually does, is modify the call from `Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize("ModelName")` to `sys=Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize("ModelName")`, so it can be done in the Commands window as well.

Answer (score 5):

Call the function from the command line and capture the output. Then you can do with it what ever you want.

Everything you find in the *Linear Analysis* toolbar is part of the library *Modelica_LinearSystems2*. The *Linearize* item in this menu calls the function

```
Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize("<your-model>")
```

which is also printed to the command line. The function returns the operator record `Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace`, which contains all the info you are interested in. The default behavior of Dymola is to call the `String` method of this operator record and print it to the command line. If you look at the source code of `Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace.'String'` you can see this at the start of the algorithm section:

```
  // If system is too large, do not print the matrices
  if size(ss.A,1) > 50 or size(ss.B, 2) > 50 or size(ss.C, 1) > 50 then
     ...
```

On the command line you can capture the operator record in a variable like this:

```
stateSpace = Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize("<your-model>");
```

And then access the values on the command line via

```
stateSpace.A
stateSpace.B
stateSpace.C
stateSpace.D
```

For a nice html report you can also pass the operator record to one of the analysis functions:

```
Modelica_LinearSystems2.StateSpace.Analysis.analysis2.printSystem(stateSpace)
```

This creates the file `systemAnalysis.html` in your working directory, containing a nice visual presentation of your system.